# Return zeros where index is out of range using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently working with a Pandas dataframe which contains 721 rows, from which I wish to select subsets of length n.

However, if the chosen subset exceeds the upper bound, I need to return zeros where the index is out of range. For example, I need `MyDataframe['Column X'][719:725]` to return `[0.998, 0.965, 0, 0, 0, 0]` (where `0.998` and `0.965` are the 720th and 721st values of my dataframe respectively).

Does pandas natively allow you to do this?

Comment: Is possible use `MyDataframe.reindex(range(726), fill_value=0)` before selecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is default index you can add new rows filled by `0` with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) before selecting:

```
MyDataframe = MyDataframe.reindex(range(726), fill_value=0)
```